# How calculate numbers in Vue 2

Tags: vuejs2

I have loop of data and I want to calculate numbers of my data, the problem is that I cannot use `+ -` in my calculator they come with the numbers like:

```
5.000
-2.000
1.000

so result should be 4.000
```

see the minus and plus comes with the numbers i need a solution for that.

## code

```
<tbody>
                <tr v-for="(history,index) in histories" @key="index">
                    <td width="50" class="text-center">{{index+1}}</td>
                    <td class="text-center" width="100">
                        {{history.created_at}}
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center" width="300">Rp. {{ formatPrice(history.balance) }}</td>
                    <td class="text-center">{{history.note}}</td>
                </tr>
</tbody>
```

PS: I do not need `* /` in my calculator, simple `+ -` would be enough.
thanks in advance.

Comment: If numbers include a sign, simply add them every time (5.00) + (-2.0) + (+1.00).

Comment: @F.Igor this is my first attempt with vue specially calculation would you mind give me sample code? so i know where and how to do it?

Comment: If you want to sum balances of the `histories` array, you need a method like `calculateTotal(histories)` (loop and sum the .balance attribute)

Comment: @F.Igor `export default {
        data() {
            return {
                histories : [],
                calculateTotal: null,
            }
        },
        methods: {
         calculateTotal(histories){
//???
         },}` how do i get balances in this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `methods` section, you can do a loop over `histories` and sum the values of each `.balance` attribute:

```
methods: { 
   calculateTotal: function(histories){
     var sum=0;
     for(var i=0;i<histories.length;i++){
       sum += histories[i].balance;
     }
     return sum;
   }
```

Then you can use it in your view, after the history rows:

```
{{calculateTotal(histories)}}
```

**Note**: If `histories` is part of the component `data`, you can access `this.histories` inside the `calculateTotal` method, without need to pass it as an argument.

Now, the method will be:

```
calculateTotal: function(){
     var sum=0;
     for(var i=0;i<this.histories.length;i++){
       sum += this.histories[i].balance;
     }
     return sum;
   }
```

And the call from view will be only

```
{{calculateTotal()}}
```

Comment: it is part of my data, `return { histories : [],` you mean i remove `function(histories)` ?

Comment: I added a second example, basically removing the parameter `histories` and using the internal value (`this.histories`)